# Reload Shiny App when using source'ed modules without restart

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I've been developing a Shiny App which started to grow rather large. 
I've solved the problem by putting different sections of the app into modules in their own files, and then sourced the files.

The problem is that, when I make changes in the server part of the sourced files (events.R in the example below, the eventsTabItems() function), I have to stop and start the App i R-Studio instead of just hitting F5 in the browser.

Is there a way around this? Do I have to wrap everything a reactive function?

Code example:

ui.R

```
source("./sections/events.R")
eventsTabItemsUI(id = "events")
```

server.R

```
source("./sections/events.R")
callModule(eventsTabItems, id = "events")
```

events.R

```
eventsTabItemsUI <- function(id) { 
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabItem(ns(example))
} 
eventsTabItems <- function(input, output, session) {
  output@example <- ...
}
```

Comment: Have you got any solutions to that, Kent? I am facing the same issue. Tak!

Answer (score 0):

I find that stopping the server before relaunching it (with the "Run App" button) is necessary whenever editing a module.  If there is javascript code in its own .js file (in the www/ folder) that you have edited, you may need to force-refresh the browser to ensure it reloads the edited code.

This answer is still experimental, so I may have missed something.  Whenever I REALLY want to ensure an edit has not broken my code, I make some minor edits to strings in my program and watch that these show up in the GUI to make sure I'm truly running the current version of the code.

---

I no longer do this:

You can set up your package to forcibly remove your functions.

```
suppressWarnings(rm("eventsTabItemsUI","eventsTabItems"))
```